# How to avoid empty file creation in Log4J2?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, appender, rollingfileappender

By default, Log4J2 creates new file independently of the fact, if there any logs to be written.

It is possible to avoid empty file creation when no logs has written to Log4J2 RollingFile appender? For me is very conveniently to see `errors.log` only when there is actual errors at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log4j 2.7 will support this: see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1501 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1504

There will be an attribute `createOnDemand` (false by default).

Comment: Thank you, will wait for it!